# cin.getline doesn't let the user to enter the value

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [cin.getline() is skipping an input in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199897/cin-getline-is-skipping-an-input-in-c)

I'm working on C++, to get some data of 2 movies like the following:

```
    struct Movie m1, m2;
    cout << "Enter first movie title: ";
    cin.getline(m1.title, 30); 
    cout << "Enter first movie director: ";
    cin.getline(m1.director, 30); 
    cout << "Enter first movie length: ";
    cin >> m1.length; 

    cout << "Enter second movie title: ";
    cin.getline(m2.title, 30);
    cout << "Enter second movie director: ";
    cin.getline(m2.director, 30); 
    cout << "Enter second movie length: ";
    cin >> m2.length;
```

But, I got surprised that in the output it doesn't all me to enter the title of the second movie. Here is the output

```
Enter first movie title: Girl

Enter first movie director: GirlD

Enter first movie length: 10

Enter second movie title: Enter second movie director: Boy

Enter second movie length: 20
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=getline+skipping. Alternatively, glance over to the column on the right labelled "Related".

Answer (score 0):

the `cin >> m1.length;`, its only read the number, so it leaves the `\n`, the next getline will read the empty line, so you can read it as this:

```
string temp;
cin.getline(temp, 30);
stringstream sst(temp);
sst >> m1.lenght;
```