# gets() not taking input

Tags: c++, gets

I have some college work and as i noticed that the gets() is not working but i can't figure out why.

I tried putting getch() and getchar() before gets() but there is something else wrong.

When i write a code implementing gets() before do-while (labeled -----> 3) it works!!!

Can somebody help me?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

class student
{
    int rollNo;
    char department[20];
    int year;
    int semester;

public:
    student()
    {
        rollNo=0;
        year=0;
        semester=0;
    }

    void getData();
    void promote();
    void changeDepartment();
    void display();
};

void student::changeDepartment()
{
    if(rollNo!=0)
    {
        cout<<"\nEnter the new Department\n";
        gets(department);                                 -------------->1
    }

    else
    {
        cout<<"\nStudent not confirmed\n";
    }
}

void student::getData()
{
    cout<<"\nEnter the roll no\n";
    cin>>rollNo;
    cout<<"\nEnter the year\n";
    cin>>year;
    cout<<"\nEnter the semester\n";
    cin>>semester;
    cout<<"\nEnter the department\n";
    gets(department);                                  ----------------> 2
}

void student::promote()
{
    if(rollNo!=0)
    {
        semester+=1;
        if(semester%2==1)
        {
            year+=1;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        cout<<"\nStudent not confirmed\n";
    }
}

void student::display()
{
    if(rollNo!=0)
    {
        cout<<"\nRoll No : "<<rollNo;
        cout<<"\nYear : "<<year;
        cout<<"\nSemester : "<<semester;
        cout<<"\nDepartment : "<<department;
    }

    else
    {
        cout<<"\nStudent not confirmed";
    }
}

int main()
{
    student s;
    int ch;
    char choice;
                                                      ----------------> 3
    do
    {
        cout<<"\nMain Menu";
        cout<<"\n1. Enter student details";
        cout<<"\n2. Change department of student ";
        cout<<"\n3. Promote student ";
        cout<<"\n4. Display student details ";
        cout<<"\nEnter your choice ";
        cin>>ch;

        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1 : s.getData();
                     s.display();
                        break;

            case 2 : s.changeDepartment();
                     s.display();
                        break;

            case 3 : s.promote();
                     s.display();
                        break;

            case 4 : s.display();
                        break;
        }

        cout<<"\nDo you want to continue? (Y/n)\n";
        cin>>choice;
    }while((choice=='y')||(choice=='Y'));

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Why are you mixing `cin` and `gets`? `gets` is an outdated C function.

Comment: Why are you mixing `cin` and `gets`?

Comment: For your own sake, never use `gets`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-is-dangerous-why-should-not-be-used

Comment: What should i use then to get strings where a space can be there?

Comment: You can use `cin.getline()`

Comment: It shows error in that case

F:\Lab\Oop Lab\5.cpp|33|error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_istream<char>::getline(char [20])'|

Comment: Did you call it with the correct parameters? You need to pass in the size of the array as the second parameter.

Comment: cin.getline(department,20);   Is this correct?

Comment: @LakshayChhikara: Yes.

Comment: @Hippo : But i cant enter anything in it now also? It just moves on to the next line where it asks if i want to continue or not.

Comment: Use `cin.ignore()` to get rid of the unwanted spaces.

Comment: @Hippo : If i give more than 20 characters then it just ends the execution of my program. Can something be done about it?

Comment: Try using `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')` to ignore unread input till the end of the line. Use `if (cin.fail())` to check if there's unread data still available - this method will return true if `getline` doesn't find a newline until it's able to read the maximum number of characters.

Comment: @Hippo : What do i have to change in this line for my code?

Comment: Nothing. Just use the `if` condition (after `getline`) and paste that call to `cin.ignore`. Also, within the `if` condition, make sure you call `cin.clear()` to clear the failure flag.

Comment: See [How do I flush the cin buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257091/how-do-i-flush-the-cin-buffer) for more information.

Comment: @Hippo : Do i have to include some header file it's showing errors like 'numeric_limits' not a member of'std' etc

Answer (score 2):

**Do not use gets**

Use `cin.getline()` instead of `gets`, wherever you're using `gets`.

```
cin.getline(department, sizeof department);
```

[`gets` is outdated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1694042/336656), because of the danger of buffer overflow since the input size cannot be specified.

**Getting rid of unwanted newlines**

In your case, `gets` was using the (undiscarded) newline from the previous input and hence storing an empty char *. Use `cin.ignore()` to get rid of the unwanted spaces - you'll need this when using `getline()` too.

Alternatively, you may always want to use `cin.getline()` to read user input in a consistent way, and then [parse the input depending on the type of data you're expecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199897/cin-getline-is-skipping-an-input-in-c/10200009#10200009). This will also allow you to perform much better error checking.

Comment: But i also used getchar() and getch() before it to test if that was the case but still there was no change?

Comment: To discard the space, you can call `cin.ignore()` immediately after you read input using `cin`. (I'm not sure why `getchar()` isn't working for you though - it works for me in gcc).

Comment: [cin.getline() is skipping an input in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10200009/183120)

Comment: @legends2k: Thanks for the comment - I've added an edit into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing C and C++. Of course, it is allowed, but there's something called an idiomatic way of using a language; meaning the language users have a natural way of expressing constructs in an elegant way. Two places where I'd suggest change:

1. Use `std::string`s instead of `char` arrays; `std::string department;`
2. Use `std::getline(std::cin, department);`

Arrays are notorious for being a rich source of bugs. Leave such low-level memory management to the standard library facilities available.

Comment: Agreed, I thought it's beating a dead horse more and more when it's already been done (comments and Hippo's answer). True, I could've added it. But I thought recommending the OP about string would completely veer him away from old habits.

Comment: This explanation was particularly intuitive to me. Thanks!